# Seemingly Contradicting Basis Concepts in Munkres's Book and that of Willard

Tags: general-topology

In S. Willard's "General Topology" he states the following theorem:
[image]

However in J. Munkres' "Topology" the author states the following lemma:
[image]

It seems to me that they are contradictory, because if for instance we consider discrete topology on some set $X$, then it is evident that $2^{X}=\mathcal{T}\neq X$. Can anyone please elucidate whether I am wrong in my deduction or not and if I am, where is my error?

Comment: Munkres is talking about a basis for a particular topology. Willard’s theorem is about using a basis to define a topology. Slightly different things.

Comment: Why should T=X in either account?

Comment: So, in Willard’s theorem, there is *some* topology with $\mathfrak B$ Is a basis for the topology. But in Munkres, we are talking about a particular topology $\mathcal T.$

Comment: Because $X=\cup_{B\in\mathcal{B}}B$ in Willard's theorem and $\mathcal{T}=\cup_{B\in\mathcal{B}}B$ in Munkres's lemma.

Comment: Well, if we are talking about some topology with $\mathcal{B}$ as basis on some set $X$ would it not include any arbitrary topology on $X$?

Comment: "Collection of all unions of elements" $\neq $ " union of all elements "

Comment: No, $\mathcal T\neq \bigcup_{B} B.$ If $X=\{1,2\}$ and $\mathcal T=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ is the discrete topology, then $\mathfrak B=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ has $$\bigcup_{B\in\mathfrak B}B=\{1\}\cup\{2\}=\{1,2\}=X\neq \mathcal T.$$

Comment: “$\mathcal T$ is the collection of all unions” does not mean $\mathcal T$ is the union.”

Comment: From what Thomas Andrews and Tim kinsella have said, I understand that Munkres was talking about $\lbrace \cup_{B\in\mathcal{B}}B\rbrace$ and Willard was talking about $\cup_{B\in\mathcal{B}}B$. Right?

Comment: No, you are misreading it still. When Munkres says that $\mathcal T$ is the collection of all unions of sets in $\mathfrak B,$ he means: $U\in \mathcal T$ iff there is a subset $C\subseteq \mathfrak B$ such that $U=\bigcup_{B\in C} B.$

Comment: Written more formally: $$\mathcal T=\{U\subseteq X\mid \exists C\subseteq\mathfrak B(U=\bigcup_{B\in C} B)\}$$

Comment: But in his proof, he mentions an element $B_{x}$ of $\mathcal B$ not a set in $B$. How is your definition equivalent to his? I'm sorry if I am being obtuse

Comment: $\mathfrak B$ is a set of sets. So an element of $\mathfrak B$ is a set. This is one reason we use these different fonts for sets. $X$ is a set of “points.” $\mathfrak B$ is a set of sets of points. $\mathcal T$ is a set of sets of points, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using your explanations and the discrete topology on $X=\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$ and $\mathfrak{B}=\lbrace\lbrace1\rbrace,\lbrace 2\rbrace,\lbrace3\rbrace\rbrace$, I think I finally understood. Just to make sure, for $U=\lbrace1,2\rbrace$ there exists $C=\lbrace\lbrace1\rbrace,\lbrace2\rbrace\rbrace\subset\mathfrak{B}$ s.t. $\cup_{B\in C}B=U$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Willard fact is about a set $X$ that has no topology yet. Then to **define** a (unique) topology on $X$ you can use a base, i.e. a family $\mathcal B$ with the two stated properties (which are just internal to $\mathcal B$ and do not refer to a topology yet) and then this newly defined topology is just the set of all unions from $\mathcal B$, i.e.

$$\mathcal T = \{O\mid \exists \mathcal B' \subseteq \mathcal B: O = \bigcup \mathcal B'\}\tag{1}$$

The fact in Munkres comes from another angle: he also discusses the properties that Willard does (they're necessary and sufficient and quite natural) but he starts with a set *with* topology $(X,\mathcal T)$ and a *base for that topology* (**not** a base to define a new topology) is a family $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal T$ (so basic sets are open in particular) so that $$\forall O \in \mathcal T: \forall x \in O: \exists B_x \in \mathcal B: x \in B_x \subseteq O\tag{2}$$

It turns out (and that is what Munkres shows in his Lemma) that a base for $\mathcal T$ as he defines it in $(2)$ is actually also a base that we could have used to define the topology as in $(1)$ (!).

So the books are perfectly consistent but take a different angle of approach, as it were.

For the discrete topology $\mathcal T=2^X$ we can use the base $\mathcal B=\{\{x\}\mid x \in X\}$ which trivially obeys the two conditions of Willard; $(b)$ is void, essentially) and as any set $A$ is a union of its singletons i.e. $A = \bigcup \{\{x\}\mid x \in A\}$ we see that every subset of $X$ is indeed a union of base sets and all those unions form the discrete topology, i.e. the power set. And $(2)$ is also clear for this base. But we don't need a base to *define* the discrete topology as $2^X$ obviously fulfills the 3 topology axioms anyway, but just to illustrate..